# Using <BODY onUnload> tag in a chrome browser running in application mode

Tags: javascript, perl, google-chrome

I am starting a chrome browser window with the command (from batch file)

c:\path\to\chrome.exe --application http://w.x.y.z/message
here is the code for  http://w.x.y.z/message

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Message Window</title>
</head>
<body onunload=window.open("http://w.x.y.z/cgi-bin/test.pl"), _blank>
<a href=http://w.x.y.z/cgi-bin/test.pl>My Long Test Meesage, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and my test.pl is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(OUTFILE, ">>/message/log/accesslog.txt");
print OUTFILE scalar localtime ();
```

this url displays a message. My desire is, when user either clicks on the text or closes the window deliberately, I want this action to invoke a cgi-bin perl script and this script to write (append)the current date and time into a predefined file.

For clicking on the URL, it is easy to make the whole message a link and tie it to the URL of my perl script.

For the case of window closure, I want the onUnload function to take effect and invoke a new (or even the same) window and run my perl script in it.

I have tested onUnlad function in plain chrome browser and it works. But the same url loaded from a chrome started as application frame, it is totally disregarded.

Why is this and does anyone know how to make it work without going and launching the browser as a regular chrome window not with --application switch.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem (from [the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onunload)):

> Browsers equipped with pop-up window blockers will ignore all window.open() method calls in onunload event handler functions.

So, what you are trying to do is impossible with `window.open()`.

Try using AJAX instead. Because you are just trying to write to a file, you simply need to pass the information, not open a new window. AJAX will do just fine for this.

Comment: unfortunately, I am a mere UNIX guy. Web technologies like AJAX is nothing more than a name that heard for me. But considering AJAX is javascript and runs on the client end, how will it help me write to a file on the server. If it can invoke my test.pl cgi-bin script, how is it going to handle that ? Again, I am not awfully familiar with AJAX framework. So, if my question is stupid, accept my apologies.

Comment: AJAX is not purely client-side; it's a means for a client to communicate with the server after the page has already loaded, using javascript. Essentially, rather than calling `window.open()`, you just call a function to send a request to your server. In this case, all it's doing is requesting `http://w.x.y.z/cgi-bin/test.pl`. Explaining AJAX is beyond the scope of an answer here, but I would suggest [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) and [this collection of tutorials](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/16/50-excellent-ajax-tutorials/).